# Error adding identity in existing .NET Core Web Application project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, scaffold

I am trying to add login functionality to a existing project using this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

However when I try to scaffold, I get this error:

[image: first page to add identity]

[image: error]

My soa_dbContext looks like this:

```
public partial class soa_dbContext : DbContext
{
    public soa_dbContext()
    {
    }

    public soa_dbContext(DbContextOptions<soa_dbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Artikel> Artikels { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual DbSet<Locatie> Locaties { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual DbSet<Rol> Rols { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual DbSet<SoaBepaling> SoaBepalings { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;

    internal static object Where(Func<object, bool> value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing **DbContext** to **IdentityDbContext** and make sure adding the
`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Here is the sample code I wrote:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebAppldentity.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```